# Having problems with TIC-80

Tags: lua

heyo! i'm trying to do a simple TIC-80 (basically lüa) script, but i'm getting an error.

error started appearing after i added the lastfaced() function. honestly idk what i did wrong.

here's the code:

```
--width and height vars
w=240
h=136

-- Last faced var
lf='r'

--Player X and Y, W, H, ID vars
p = {
id=0,
x=w/2,
y=h/2,
w=16,
h=16,
draw = function()
    spr(p.id, p.x, p.y, 1, 1)
end
}

   --movement function here


function lastfaced()
    if btn(2) then
        lf='l'
        
    elseif btn(3) then
        lf='r'

    elseif lf="l" then
        p.id=4
        
    elseif lf="r" then
        p.id=0
    end
end
    
function TIC()
    cls(12)
    
    move()
    p.draw()
    lastfaced()
    
end
```

and here's the error:

```
[string "..."]:49: 'then' expected near '='
```

can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Ehm, when you want to compare you must use == for it to work, one = will not work...

```
function lastfaced()
    if btn(2) then
        lf='l'
        
    elseif btn(3) then
        lf='r'

    elseif lf="l" then
        p.id==4
        
    elseif lf=="r" then
        p.id=0
    end
end
```

Comment: `if lf=="l" then p.id=4`  Don't use second `elseif` at that point, it'll take an extra game loop for screen to update.